# Adicionar novos campos dinamicamente

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou criando um *app* que calcula créditos de um boletim escolar.

**DUVIDA**: Como para adicionar um novo `EditText` quando o usuário clicar no botão "+" ao lado e somar os valores de cada `EditText`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma forma bem simples seria trabalhar com ListView, criei uma ListViewAdapter que contenha os campos que deseja e adicione um nova linha a cada click no botão "+".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simples exemplo de `EditText` com `ListView`:

**XML** - { `main.xml` }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Add" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML** - { `item_edittext.xml` }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ItemCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:singleLine="true"></EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java** - { `Main.class` }

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnAdd;

    private ArrayList arrTemp = new ArrayList();

    private ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    MyListAdapter myListAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        array.add("teste");

        arrTemp.add(array);

        myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        array.add("teste");
        myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (array != null && array.size() != 0) {
                return array.size();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return array.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = Main.this.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_edittext, null);

                holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.ref = position;

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            EditText editText1;
            int ref;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe algum nome para esta função que eu pedi? Algo que eu possa pesquisar mais a fundo para entender o funcionamento detalhado?

Comment: Pesquiso sempre em inglês, então p/ este seu caso eu iria busca no Google assim: [dynamically add edittext android](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=dynamically+add+edittext+android&oq=Dynamically+add+e) ... uma das maneira de fazer isso dinamicamente é inserir realmente em uma lista, porque imagina se você for colocar 30 `edittext's`, ai iria ultrapassar sua tela, a não ser que insira um `scrollview`, mas não seria uma boa prática. Crie o hábito de buscar em inglês, vai ter mais sucesso nas resposta. Abraços. Vlw. Flw @BrunoAssisdeTassis

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que você pode adicionar um novo botton, com o addView.

Exemplo:
"linearLayout.addView(botton);"

Exemplo que tenho aqui:

```
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scroll_crews, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.scroll_crew_liner);
View layoutScroll = view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_crews_linearlayout);    
TextView textCrewJob = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCrewJob);    
TextView textCrewNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCrewNome);
ImageView imgPagerCrews = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPagerCrews);
ProgressBar progressBarCrew = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarCrews);    
linearLayout.addView(layoutScroll);
```

No exemplo, inflo uma xml, e com ele edito o que preciso e apos isso adiciono ele em outro layout.

Aonde você precisa adicionar o botton, de um findViewById() no layout e com ele, fala um layout.addView();