# Adicionar formulários por meio de um botão

Tags: android

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de lista de supermercado, e nesse aplicativo o usuario cadastra os produtos da lista, e depois salva a mesma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário digita o nome do produto e ao quantidade,e eo clicar no botão adicionar, outro form identido aparece abaixo, para ele colcoar mais itens na sua lista
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já pensei em fazer com list view e adapter, mas mesmo assim, ainda não tenho ideia de como produzir isso.
Alguém tem alguma ideia?
Obrigado

Comment: O ideal é fazer um Listview para poder listar estes produtos. O que você pode fazer é adicionar um botão fixo ma parte de baixo da tela e criar um Dialogo para adicionar estes produtos. No momento que você adicionar, ai você atualiza sua lista.

Comment: Talvez eu tenha me expressado mal, mas o que na verdade estaria no lsit view, não seria a lista de produtos cadastrados, e sim os formulario, tipo: insira o produto, insira a quantidade, e ai quando eu clico em adicionar ele me da mais um formulario desse, para caso eu queira cadastrar mais produtos. Na iamgem, Produto, e qaunt, seriam os campos do formulario

Comment: Independente do que seja, quando é dinâmico, geralmente é mais interessante você usar listview. No entanto, caso não queira usar listview, você terá que colocar um scrollview no seu layout, pois quando atingir o limite máximo da tela, você ainda sim continuará vendo os elementos. Use como base essa minha resposta caso queira fazer em um listview: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152212/35406

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. :D Vlw!!